# Visual Studio 2012 not generating symbol (.pdb) files

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

I have a project in VS2012 where debugging is not available; if I set a breakpoint, it tells me that
"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

In the properties of the project, *Generate debug info* is set to full and *optimizations* are disabled (so the symbol files *should* be generated automatically...).
When inspecting the modules while in debug mode, the paths of the dlls are in the Temporary ASP.NET files folder, but no pdb files are to be found in that location. To be more specific; In the above mentioned folder, there are three subfolders (each named a seemingly random string of hex), and in **one** of these folders the dlls and pdbs are paired nicely for each module, however in the other two folders this is not the case, as only the dlls are present. Unfortunately VS is looking in one of the latter folders, thus not being able to find the symbol files.
Whenever I try to load in a symbol file manually for a dll, it tells me that symbol file isn't the right one; I assume it has to come from the exact same build as the dll. So I know where to put them, but I don't know where they are...

Since this folder is hidden (it's located in my AppData folder) and named "temporary...", I assume the files are loaded in automatically and that I shouldn't mess around with it.
So what do I do?
I know this is an extremely vague question, but I'm very ignorant when it comes to stuff like this, so some general guidance would be very much appreciated! Otherwise feel free to ask further elaborating questions - I'll do my very best to answer them.

**P.S.** I'm aware that very similar questions have been asked on here multiple times, but browsing through a lot of them, I still haven't found a solution that works for me, so I thought a new question where I can give you the exact details of my situation was appropriate - let me know if that is not the case, and I'll make sure to delete this post :)

Comment: The location of the PDB file is *also* encoded into the binary file.  Normally points to the project's obj\Debug directory.  So not having a copy of the pdb in the same place as the dll is not normally a problem.  Use Debug > WIndows > Modules > locate the DLL in the list > right click > Symbol Load Information.  Tells you where the debugger looked for the PDB file.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Though I still have the problem of actually locating the true pdb files before I can relocate them; I now know where they're supposed to be, but I don't know where they actually are...
Surely I must have moved some files at some point in the past, since it seems unlikely that they have just dissapeared..

Answer (score 1):

1)Please check that which pdb file or symbol file was not really loaded, you could visit the debug Modules windows and find the information. Or you could visit the Output window, it would show you which pdb file was not found.

(2)Enable the Microsoft Symbol Servers under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols.

[image]

(3) Clean and Rebuild the solution, and make sure no compiled error, and then re-debug your app. Of course, you could visit the cache folder for the symbol servers, check that whether it has the pdb file which was not found before.

(4) If you find the pdb file,  as Hans Passant's suggestion, you could also load the symbols manually in the Modules window:

1.Right-click in the debug Modules window, select Load Symbols From, then click Symbol Path or Microsoft Symbol Servers.

If the debugger doesn’t find the symbols, it would show the Find Symbols dialog.

2.In the Find Symbols dialog, locate the symbols file that you want to load.
The symbols file is a .pdb file or a .dbg file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Unfortunately neither of them seemed to have worked. About 80% of my symbols aren't loading; some of them are Microsoft related and some of them are 'my own'. The cache is empty, eventhough I have tried caching symbols before in an attempt to improve performace. The problem with loading them manually is, that I have 10-20 symbol files lying around from previous version etc., and they don't seem to work, so I assume the pdb file must be from the exact same build as the dll - even if the source code is identical..

Comment: @Rasmus Eskesen, Tools->Options->Debugging, disable "Require source files to exactly match the original version", and then re-debug your app again. Or re-compile and generate the matched symbols if you use previous versions.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but unfortunately no luck. Good suggestion though.

Comment: @Rasmus Eskesen, just to make this issue clearly, (1)could you find the pdb file if you use the windows research in your local machine?(2) Which symbols/pdb file generated this issue? If it was a reference, do you compile it using the same .NET Framework like .NET 4.5 and same Platform Target(Any CPU/x86/X64)?(3) How about creating a new solution for this project in a new path(Please also run VS as the admin)?

Comment: @Rasmus Eskesen, what about this issue? Do you get any latest information about it?